# Power monitor over usb-c

Tags: display, usb-c

I was wondering if I would be able to power a monitor over usb-c since normal power cables are pretty clunky. The power should be sufficient as it provides up to 100W with the right cable.

Is it possible to both power a monitor over usb and send a video signal from a pc to the monitor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unless the monitor is designed with this in mind.

Monitors are designed to be powered with 100-120V AC or 220-240V AC, depending on the region. Then monitor's internal power supply adjusts this voltage to DC that powers all discrete components. I don't think AC is used directly in modern LCDs.

USB-PD provides 5-20V DC. That's not what the monitor needs.

The monitor could be designed to be powered by USB-PD. In that case instead of AC-DC converter it would have a single DC-DC converter producing required voltage.

Answer (score 0):

Voltage is your issue. The monitor will need a 110 or 230v supply, USB-C won't carry that sort of voltage.

Answer (score 0):

No monitor relies exclusively on 110V/220V AC. Internally, they convert AC 110V/220V to a voltage closer to 20V. Therefore, it's feasible to implement a DIY solution using a USB-C Trigger Board.

A notable example is a YouTuber named Linux, who has successfully done this with various products. You can view the process here: [Linux's USB-C Project on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kZOe7aaiqqE&t=11s).

Additionally, there's an ongoing discussion about this topic on Linus Tech Tips Forum: [USB-C Power Conversion Discussion](https://linustechtips.com/topic/1470228-how-to-put-usb-c-power-on-anything-almost/).

Here's a link to some useful Trigger Boards: [USB-C Trigger Boards on AliExpress](https://pt.aliexpress.com/item/1005005994580444.html).

As further evidence, I found a video of a monitor teardown and repair that clearly shows the monitor only requires a 20V input: [Monitor Teardown Video on YouTube.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_hGsKTs0rCQ)

PS: It's worth noting that recent USB Power Delivery (PD) standards even support up to 48V.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).